# Unable to write to a database with python program

Tags: python, mysql

Ive been trying to write data to a MySQL database via a python program I wrote, but haven't had much luck. The program is broken up into functions. I'm however getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'encode'

This is the code for the database module:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error 

def creat_connection(host_name, user_name, user_pasword, db_name):
    """Function that establishes a connection to the database"""
    connection = None 

    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = host_name,
            user = user_name,
            password = user_pasword, 
            database = db_name

        )
        print('Connection to MySQL database successful!!')
    except Error as e: 
        print(f"The error '{e}' occurred")

    return connection
```

```
def buildQuery(idnum, name, gpa, tuition, status):
    """A function that builds an insert query"""

    create_student_app =(""" INSERT INTO grant_applicants(grantID, student_name, student_gpa, tuition_shortfall, grant_status)
                            VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {}, {}) """).format(idnum, name, gpa, tuition, status)

    return create_student_app


def execute_query(conn, query):
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    try:
        cursor.execute(query, query)
        connection.commit()
        print("Student data uploaded successfully!!")   
    except Error as e:
        print(f"The error '{e}' occurred.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_query(connection, buildQuery)
```

I feel like I'm missing something with the execute_query() function.

Comment: This is not right: `cursor.execute(query, query)` you can't expect it to work...

Comment: Did you try this https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp ?

Comment: Yeah i added that while i was troubleshooting the issue and forgot to remover it before posting the code here. The still doesn't solve the issue. I'm currently on RealPython.com, I'll take a look at the link you included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the `buildQuery` function instead of its results to your `execute_query`, I would also suggest using the a prepared statement instead of building the query like you've done as to avoid any formatting issues with the query itself:

```
def buildQuery(idnum, name, gpa, tuition, status):
    """A function that builds an insert query"""

    create_student_app ="""
    INSERT INTO grant_applicants(grantID, student_name, student_gpa, tuition_shortfall, grant_status)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    """

    return {
        'query': create_student_app,
        'params': (idnum, name, gpa, tuition, status)
    }


def execute_query(conn, query, params):
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    try:
        cursor.execute(query, params)
        connection.commit()
        print("Student data uploaded successfully!!")   
    except Error as e:
        print(f"The error '{e}' occurred.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_query(connection, **buildQuery())
```

This is just a modified version of what you have but you're free to refactor it based on your needs, its just to demonstrate what you need.

Comment: I figured it out using a different code structure. I'll also try this and see how it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The line `execute_query(connection, buildQuery)` is sending the function `buildQuery` , not the result of its call. It should be something like

`execute_query(connection, buildQuery(...your params here))`

There are other problems with your code, but this is what causing this specific issue